# How to connect Opto esc to BLDC Motor

Tags: esc, brushless-motors

I'm using 30A Opto 2-4s LIPo Blheli-S ESC for my drone. And I'm currently confused about how to connect the BLDC motor to the ESC. I found nothing online that currently explains the type of connections for my ESC type.

> ESC: 30A BLHELI-S Opto

> MOTOR: A2212/6T 2200KV

https://i.stack.imgur.com/umnZS.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFjRa.jpg

Answer (score 3):

The signal generated by the `ESC` is a sine wave, where between each of the three output wires there is an phase difference of `120°`.

I suggest you use some connector to solder on the ends of the wires and on the `ESC` output. Then, you simply connect a motor wire to an `ESC` output. If you don't have or don't want to use a connector, just solder.

When turn on, if the motor turns in a direction you don't want, you have two options:

1. Configure the radio/controller to invert the `ESC` signal
2. Exchange two `ESC` or motor wires between them

For exemple:

The motor wire are `M1`, `M2` and `M3`, and the `ESC` output is `ESC1`, `ESC2` and `ESC3`.
So, connect:

`M1`===`ESC1`

`M2`===`ESC2`

`M3`===`ESC3`

If the motor turns in a direction you don't want, exchange the connections like:

`M1`===`ESC3`

`M2`===`ESC2`

`M3`===`ESC1`

Comment: I'm looking for the connection guide. In a picture I found online they connected the middle(black) to the end of ESC and the yellow to the end of ESC. Is that the proper connection to make or do I have to connect all the wires in serial

Comment: You must connect the wires individually, not in series or in parallel. [Look this tutorial](https://blog.dronetrest.com/how-to-connect-motors-and-esc/).

Comment: Yeah, this is the picture I'm talking about. Are those the correct way to connect the Opto esc to the motor. What about the reverse rotations?

Comment: Exchange the motor input wires in the `ESC` output wires. I will update the post with a exemple.